# gdalwarp cutline along with shapefile

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to clip my Raster file according to a shapefile geometry. I am using the following code

```
gdalwarp -cutline INPUT.shp INPUT.tif OUTPUT.tif
```

But it is resulting a black color outside the shapefile geometry extent. I am giving the example here. In the first Image that I want to clip. The second image is the resultant raster but I want the 3rd Raster where the outside of the geometry will be null.

[image: 1st Image: INPUT Raster]

1st Image: INPUT Raster

[image: 2nd Image: OUTPUT Raster]

2nd Image: OUTPUT Raster

[image]

3rd Image: I want to get output like this

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to use the `-dstalpha` option to `gdalwarp` e.g.:

```
gdalwarp -cutline INPUT.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha INPUT.tif OUTPUT.tif
```

This will add an alpha band to the output tiff which masks out the area falling outside the cutline.

A late answer, but hopefully it will help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: without the -srcnodata <in> -dstnodata <out> hint by Curlew it did not work for me.

Comment: Well, `-dstalpha` is OK to use with imagery (it basically adds an alpha Band in GeoTIFF and mask the area). However, data values remains in the source Band (in this case I guess, that it is value 0). If you want to work with this as raster values (not imagery), `-dstalpha` is WRONG approach.@Curlew answer is much preferable option. Also, I found `-crop_to_cutline` option very dangerous, if you need to keep exact overlay (pixel-size and spacing) with the input raster. I prefer to set `-te` options (bounding box) to keep coordinates under full control.

Comment: gdalwarp -cutline Eastcoast.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha "myrasterfinal77.tif" "demUTM12.tif"

Getting invalid syntax

Answer (score 29):

Try to specify the nodata-value from your input raster and set it for the output as well. Furthermore add the option -crop_to_cutline to make exact crops. More about the options [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata <in> -dstnodata <out> -crop_to_cutline -cutline INPUT.shp INPUT.tif OUTPUT.tif
```

Comment: Can You elaborate little bit more?
What is used as <in> and <out> ?

Comment: <in> is your input rasters nodata-value and <out> for your output-raster. Please have a look at the provided link where you can find all information and options (output format, source, extent, ... )

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax, can u help me with this    

gdalwarp -srcnodata "myrasterfinal77.tif" -dstnodata "demUTM12.tif" -crop_to_cutline -cutline "Eastcoast.shp" "myrasterfinal77.tif" "demUTM12.tif"

Answer (score 2):

You can use raster clip option in QGIS which runs gdalwarp in the background and configures the right options for you.

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html

Comment: I want a ***.tif format

Comment: The steps outlined in the link above should give you a .tif output.

Comment: The link seems dead.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov browsed a bit and found where it was moved, fixed it