# Cut shapefile with a raster file?

Tags: gdal

How do I clip a shapefile with a raster file with gdalwarp?

Input: a shapefile
Cutter: a raster file
Output: a cut shapefile

I can only find the answer of cutting the raster file by a shapefile but not vice versa.

Comment: related (the opposite) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45053/gdalwarp-cutline-along-with-shapefile (maybe a clue?)

Comment: Do you want to cut by the extent of the raster? See Vector->Research Tool->Extract Layer Extent, and make an intersection Vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Intersection.

Comment: @Mapperz: I've tried to switch the shapefile and raster, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Zoltan: I know I can do it with qgis, but I am looking for a gdal function to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the data extent of the raster e.g. with [gdal-dans-scripts](https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts) (`apt install dans-gdal-scripts`) by using gdal_trace_outline like (ndv is the no data value that will be not considered so if you need to clip with certain value you can create a mask before):

```
gdal_trace_outline clipper_image.tif -ndv 0 -dp-toler 10 -min-ring-area 10000  -no-donuts -ogr-out clipper_shape.shp
```

Also you can try to vectorize your raster e.g. with [gdal_polygonize](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html).

And then clip with ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr your_shape_to_be_clipped.shp -clipsrc clipper_shape.shp final_clip.shp
```